# groovy - connect to soap php webservice

Tags: php, soap, groovy

I try to connect and get data from a webservice where the endpoint is no wsdl but a weird php page, such as : /sync/soap.php?v=7

when calling the address in firefox I download the wsdl file. Using SOAPui it

What should I do to be able to do that using groovy ? use GroovyWS? I did not find anything dealing with such a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

wsdl - is a document that describes web service.

you can use soapui to call the required method from this service.

then on `Raw` tab of request in soapui you can see all http headers and xml body that you have to POST to endpoint:

[image]

so you can use any http library to call such a service